# Jquery Combine SlideUp/Down and on click

Tags: jquery, onclick, slide

I have created two scripts, one which has slide up and slide down commands which work on timers when the page is loaded. The second is a click event where a slideup/down command is executed when a link is clicked. Both these scripts work separately but I cannot get them to work together.

Here is the timed slideup/down script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slide-out-div').hide();
    $('.slide-out-div')
        .delay(5000)
        .slideDown(300);
    $('.slide-out-div')
        .delay(5000)
        .slideUp(500);
});
```

Here is the click script:

```
window.onload = function() {
    $(document).('#clickme').click(function () {
        if ($('.slide-out-div').is(":hidden")) {
            $('.slide-out-div').slideDown("slow");
        } else {
            $('.slide-out-div').slideUp("slow");
        }
    });
};
```

How this is supposed to work is when the page is loaded the box slides down after a few seconds, then if the box is not used it slides up after a few seconds. At this point the link can be clicked to make the box slide up or down depending on its current position.

Any help getting these two to work in combination is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use timeout functions like so:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/SW6Mv/6/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var timer;
    $('.slide-out-div').slideDown('slow', function () {
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $('.slide-out-div').slideUp("slow");
        }, 5000);
    });
    $('#clickme').click(function () {
        if ($('.slide-out-div').is(":hidden")) {
            $('.slide-out-div').slideDown('slow', function () {
                timer = setTimeout(function () {
                    $('.slide-out-div').slideUp("slow");
                }, 5000);
            });
        } else {
            $('.slide-out-div').slideUp('slow');
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, however it does not seem to work properly. When the link is clicked the box slides down and straight back up, I have found this also happens on your example if you play with it for a minute.

Comment: @Paul did you want the div to slide back up after a certain time after click as well? or were you looking for something more like this- http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/SW6Mv/3/

Answer (score 1):

use callback function -

```
$('.slide-out-div')
    .delay(5000)
    .slideDown(300, function () {
    $('.slide-out-div')        // execute when slideDown is complete
        .delay(5000)
        .slideUp(500);
});
```

---

```
$('#clickme').click(function () {
    if ($('.slide-out-div').is(":hidden")) {
        $('.slide-out-div').end().slideDown("slow");
    } else {
        $('.slide-out-div').end().slideUp("slow");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But this seems to be an alternative time slide script, it doesn't incorporate the click event.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The new script allows the click event but stops the timed event from functioning. This is where I've been going round in circles :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [`.clearQueue()`](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/)?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var slideOut = $('.slide-out-div'), //cache DOM lookup
        tease = function () { //functionize this, in case you want to re-use it
            slideOut.slideDown(300);
            slideOut.delay(5000).slideUp(500);
        };
    $('#clickme').click(function (e) {
        /*
         * clearQueue() clears the [default] animation queue
         * so the slide-out div will behave correctly
         * if #clickme is clicked while tease() is running.
         */
        if (slideOut.is(":hidden")) {
            slideOut.clearQueue().slideDown("slow");
        } else {
            slideOut.clearQueue().slideUp("slow");
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
    tease(); //tease with the slide-out
});
```

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/y5vGR/**

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this script however when clicking the link for the box to slide up it jumps to the hidden position and then slides down again (as if it this the box is currently hidden). I have copied your code and not sure when this is happening :S

Comment: Is this happening in the fiddle or when you tried integrating it into your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code for toggle

```
    <div class="panel">
            <br />
            <br />
            <p>The panel text or login and registraion form goes here....</p>
            <p>sanwebcorner.com</p>
            </div>
            <p class="slide"><a href="#" class="pull-me">Slide Up/Down</a></p>


 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pull-me').click(function() {
        $('.panel').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```