# Pull out / slide up div from bottom?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, slide

I'd like to have some sort of 'chat' window slide up from the bottom when you click on the link/image. I've tried it myself first but I couldn't figure it out.
Did some searching here and on other websites ... but apparently I'm not very good at this.

I looked at this aswell, but I couldn't get it working for me: [Pull out a div from the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17372346/pull-out-a-div-from-the-bottom)

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pbdr2umc/) is what I have so far:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="onlinehulp">
    <div id="clickme"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/hv3Rkf8.png">
        </div>
        <div id="contact-online">
        </div>
</div>
```

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
$( "#contact-online" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
});
$('#onlinehulp').animate({bottom: '218px'}, 'slow');
});
```

I got it working so the window slides up when we click on the image, but when we click the image again it won't slide down, even though the actual window does disappear and slides back.

Anyone able to push me in the right direction?

Comment: check this link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316156/jquery-combine-slideup-down-and-on-click"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To slide up, you need to animate back to bottom: 0px. To know if you the popup is open you can use a class:

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
    $( "#contact-online" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {

    });

    if ($('#onlinehulp').hasClass('open')) {
        //close it
        $('#onlinehulp').animate({bottom: '0px'}, 'slow', function() {
            $('#onlinehulp').removeClass('open'); 
        });
    } else {
        // open it
        $('#onlinehulp').animate({bottom: '218px'}, 'slow', function() {
            $('#onlinehulp').addClass('open');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Do I have to change anything in the HTML and/or CSS as well, adding an 'open' class that does some magic? It won't budge at all now.

Sorry this is basically my first time using jquery.

Comment: No, the class is only a flag for your javascript program to know if the onlinehulp div is visible

Comment: There is a small syntax error and I edited it. Please check syntax before posting. With out it this is correct answer. Ignore one I posted..

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
    $( "#contact-online" ).slideToggle( "slow");
    if($(this).hasClass('hide')){
        $('#onlinehulp').animate({bottom: '0px'}, 'slow');
        $(this).removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
    } else {
        $('#onlinehulp').animate({bottom: '218px'}, 'slow');
        $(this).removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
    }
});
```

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/pbdr2umc/3/).

Comment: @Jelmer Jasper's answer is correct. It is more useful. There was a small syntax error in that.

Comment: @Jelmer if it works then you should appreciate the effort with a vote cause he deserves it and it may help future users looking for the same